# Rally Custom App: Need to get all current Rally releases

Tags: rally

I'm trying to write a filter that will yield all the releases in a Rally project that are current, defined as starting before or on today, and ending after today.

```
    var today = new Date();

    var releaseDateFilter = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
        property : 'ReleaseDate',
        operator : '>',
        value : today
    });

    var releaseFilter = releaseDateFilter.and(Ext.create(
            'Rally.data.wsapi.Filter', {
                property : 'ReleaseStartDate',
                operator : '<=',
                value : today
            }));

    console.log(releaseFilter.toString());

    var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store',
            {
                model : 'Release',
                fetch : [ 'FormattedID', 'Name', 'ReleaseDate',
                        'ReleaseStartDate' ],
                limit : Infinity,
                filters : releaseFilter,
                context : {
                    project : '/project/XXXXXXX',
                    projectScopeDown : true
                },
                autoLoad : true,
                listeners : {
                    load : function(myStore, myData, mySuccess) {
                        // Do stuff here
                    },
                    scope : this
                }
            });
```

The console.log output of the filter:

```
((ReleaseDate > Thu Feb 06 2014 11:54:26 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)) AND
 (ReleaseStartDate <= Thu Feb 06 2014 11:54:26 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)))
```

The data store has no records in it.  If I comment out the filter, the data store has 289 records.

When I try this query through Rally's WSAPI help page, I get 129 releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates in Rally's Webservices API need to be formatted as ISO8601 strings, i.e.:

`2014-02-06T11:10:14.000Z`

Try using [Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.util.DateTime-method-toIsoString) as follows:

`var today = Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(new Date());`

And your filter should work as you expect.

Comment: I just figured that out.  Silly me.  Thanks for the quick reply!